# <HTML> Can't select same values in drop down list. Validation <HTML>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to validate my drop down lists.

There are 6 destinations, and if the user was to select Cardiff in the "Departure" drop down, then if they was to select Cardiff again in the "Destination" drop downn, it should give a message box saying 'Destination can't be the same as Departure'.

This needs to be done in HTML and JavaScript/JQuery.

Thanks

```
Departure: <br> <select> 
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
        <option>Birmingham</option>
        <option>Bristol</option>
        <option>Cardiff</option>
        <option>Liverpool</option>
        <option>London</option>
        <option>Manchester</option>
</select><br><br>

Destination: <br><select>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
        <option>Birmingham</option>
        <option>Bristol</option>
        <option>Cardiff</option>
        <option>Liverpool</option>
        <option>London</option>
        <option>Manchester</option>
</select><br><br>
```

Comment: Just from a usability standpoint, it might make more sense not to even display duplicate options in the other select box.

Comment: @J4G I know how to do that. But I don't want that to happen. I need to display a messagebox.

Comment: What code have you achieved? Can you post?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I can't seem to do it in anyway. I've tried but deleted my javascipt =/ I know there is something to do with "id"

Comment: I find it hard to believe you know how to remove an option from a select but not how to check for equality between two inputs' values in the onSubmit method of the form to raise an alert before returning false. Anyway here is your solution.

Comment: Doesn't sound very user friendly

Comment: @Aaron I got the code to remove the option but that's not the point I'm posting to ask for help.

Comment: And have you read my comment to its end?

Comment: @charlietfl I know it doesn't sound user friendly to display a messagebox, but it has to be done =S

Comment: So what doesn't answer your question in "check for equality between two inputs' values in the onSubmit method of the form to raise an alert before returning false" ?

Comment: @Aaron I have absolutely no idea how to execute this

Comment: This is basic javascript and that's why I'm acting like an asshole. I'm being vaguely sorry now but seriously you should check a few javascript tutorials rather than just using AtheistP3ace's solution and learning nothing from it.

Answer (score 3):

Very quick example but essentially you can do something like this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hojsqhr/

```
$('#select1, #select2').on('change',
    function () {
        if ($('#select1').val() == $('#select2').val()) {
            // Display message
        }
        else {
            // Remove message if displayed
        }
    }
);
```

Well I am feeling slightly called out so let me explain what is happening here.

```
$('#select1, #select2').on('change',
```

First I select the two inputs we want to test against and attach a change event to them. This will fire this event every time the input's value changes and loses focus.

```
if ($('#select1').val() == $('#select2').val()) {
    // Display message
}
else {
    // Remove message if displayed
}
```

In this function we get both values of the two inputs we want to test for equivalent values. If they are the same we display the message. If not don't do anything or in some cases remove a displayed message.

Again this is a very quick solution that can be much more dynamic and thought out depending on your specific scenario. This is very simple JavaScript/jQuery. I would recommend doing some reading and perhaps free courses online that can teach these basics. A simple google search will pull up a ton of examples of code like this and websites that teach how to do this.

Comment: There was no calling you out, you were just the only answer ! Sorry I made you feel that way ! Anyway congratulations for explaining in depth, I should have done as much instead of lashing out on the asker.

Comment: @Aaron No worries! I didn't mean it negatively. I should have explained the solution. You were correct! You made me strive to be a better answer! =]